# Object Messaging Terminology?

Tags: objective-c

I am just curious, I am writing some notes for a friend and am not sure how to best refer to whats happening here ...

```
[myObject display];
```

1. access the object by calling display
2. access the object by messaging display
3. access the object by sending the display message
4. other ...

Just want to make sure I get the terminology right.

gary

Comment: oftentimes with c it's easier to read things backward

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Strictly speaking the call "sends the `display` message to `myObject`".

However, it's equally understood, and often simpler, to say "call the `display` method of `myObject`".
In most cases the expressions are equivalent - but the first reveals more about what is going on, and where things may differ (the object may intercept the message and do something else with it other than call the method).

Answer (score 4):

You're sending the display message to myObject or you're telling myObject to display.

You're not accessing myObject, you're telling it to do something.

Answer (score 2):

I would say: Send `display` to `myObject`.